The exact sequence for a derived zero locus
For a locally free sheaf of rank one $L$ on a derived scheme and a morphism $s:L\rightarrow O_{X}$, we consider the derived zero locus of $s$ defined by the following derived fiber product
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
D @>i>> X \\
@VVV @VVsV \\
X @>0>> V = \operatorname{Spec}_X(\operatorname{Sym}^*(L)).
\end{CD}$$
Here $D$ is the derived zero locus of the section $s$.
Now let's recall the classical case for an effective Cartier divisor which is the zero locus of the regular section $s:L\rightarrow O_{X}$, there is an exact sequence of $O_{X}$ module sheaves:  $0\rightarrow L\cong O_{X}(-D)\cong \rightarrow O_{X}\rightarrow i_{*}O_{D} \rightarrow 0$. Here the isomorphism $L\rightarrow O_{X}(D)=I_{D}\subset O_{X}$ is the section $s$ with restriction on the codomain because the zero locus is defined exactly by the ideal sheaf $I$ as the image ideal sheaf of the section $s$.
Thus the sheaf $L$ is isomorphic to the fiber of the morphism $O_{X}\rightarrow i_{*}O_{D}$ induced by the closed scheme immersion $i$.
I want to extend this isomorphism to the derived case for the derived zero locus $D$ defined as above, which is true, as it is used implicitly in the proof of proposition 3.26 of 'Virtual Cartier divisors and blow-ups' by Khan and Rydh.
Question: How do we prove $L\cong \operatorname{fib}(O_{X}\xrightarrow{i^{\#}} i_{*}O_{D})$ in the derived context?
The classical case is based on the construction of zero locus directly as the image ideal sheaf of the section $s:L\rightarrow O_{X}$, but for the derived schemes, there is no such construction of 'derived image ideal sheaf' to construct a closed derived sub scheme. Instead, I hope we can get the consequence of this isomorphism directly from the cartesian diagram used to construct the derived zero locus, which I believe should use the following things:

The universal property of the symmetric algebra.

The cotangent complex, because $L_{X/V}\cong L$. And also as the fiber of $O_{X}\rightarrow i_{*}O_{D}$, $O_{X}(-D)|_{D}$ is exactly the conormal sheaf in the classical case, while in the derived case of quasi-smooth immersion, we define the conormal sheaf as shifted cotangent complex $L_{D/X}[-1]$ (in 'Virtual Cartier divisors and blow-ups'), so I believe there must be some manipulation of cotangent complex here.

The cartesian diagram. But I can't directly transform the limit diagram in the infinity category of derived schemes to some limit diagram of quasi-coherent sheaves on a fixed derived scheme, even for the classical schemes, I never know any techniques to do so.


Update:
Following the answer by @Z. M, by the proof of 25.2.4.1, for the exact sequence $0\rightarrow L_{1}\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} L_{2}\rightarrow L_{3}\rightarrow 0 $, we have Koszul resolution $\DeclareMathOperator\LSym{LSym}\wedge^{\cdot}L_{1}\otimes_{R}^{L} \LSym^{*}(L_{2})\rightarrow \LSym^{*}(L_{3})\rightarrow 0$. Take $L_{1}=L_{2}=0$ and p=id, then we have the exact sequence $\DeclareMathOperator\LSym{LSym}
I\otimes_R^L\LSym_R^{*}(I)\longrightarrow\LSym_R^{*}(I)\xrightarrow0R$. After derived tensor product with the $\DeclareMathOperator\LSym{LSym}(-)\otimes_{\LSym^{*}(L)} R$ induced by the section $s$, the sequence is again exact : $\DeclareMathOperator\LSym{LSym} I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R\otimes_{\LSym^{*}(L)} R$.

The word "derived" does not seem to appear in the title of the paper you cite, so I edited to match the title on the arXiv.  I hope that that was all right. \ Your exact sequence of $O_X$-module sheaves has "$L\cong O_{X}(-D)\cong \rightarrow O_{X}$".  Is that "$\cong\rightarrow$" really what you intended?

Sorry for my type error.  Yes，I want to extend this exact sequence $L\rightarrow O_X \rightarrow i_* O_D $ in the infinity category $QCoh(X)$.

First, concerning your third question, it is not a random pullback diagram, but with two legs being affine. In this case, roughly speaking, the pullback is "computed" by the (derived) tensor product, and without loss of generality, we may consider the case that $\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}X=\Spec(R)$ is affine. Let $I$ denote the (invertible) $R$-module corresponding to the line bundle $L$, which is equipped with a map $s\colon I\to R$ of $R$-modules.
To understand better what is happening here, we start with the case that the line bundle $L$ is trivial. In this case, we are reduced to computing the tensor product $R\otimes_{R[t]}^LR$, where the maps $R[t]\to R$ are given by $t\mapsto 0$ and induced by $s$ respectively. Your identification essentially follows from the resolution
$$
R[t]\xrightarrow{(-)\cdot t}R[t]\xrightarrow{t\mapsto0}R.
$$
This resolution extends to the general case as well:
$$\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}
I\otimes_R^L\Sym_R(I)\longrightarrow\Sym_R(I)\xrightarrow0R,
$$
which is the Koszul resolution associated to the fiber sequence $I\to I\to0$, cf. Prop 2 of Lecture 13 of Dustin Clausen's course on algebraic de Rham cohomology, or the proof of Prop 25.2.4.1 in Lurie's Spectral Algebraic Geometry.

Thanks for your answer! So here the fiber sequence $I\rightarrow I\rightarrow 0$ is the identity morphism, right? And by the third part of prop 2 of your first reference, we have $\wedge^{\cdot} ker(I\rightarrow I)\cong \wedge^{\cdot}(I)\otimes Sym^{*}(I)$, then we get the exact sequence $I\otimes^{L}{R}Sym{R}(I)\rightarrow Sym_{R}(I)\rightarrow R$, is this right?

I have just updated my question following your answer, am I right in this way?

@Yang If the context is clear (e.g. in derived algebraic geometry), one usually omits the initial letter L in LSym. It would be ambiguous only when you would also consider the $E_\infty$ version, namely, the homotopy $\Sigma_n$-orbits of the $n$-th tensor power.

Sorry I just want to ask that when we say $R[t]\rightarrow R[t]\rightarrow R$ is a resolution, we mean it is exact in $Mod(R)$, right? But indeed it's exact in $Mod(R)^{discrete}$ but are you sure this is exact in infinity category of $Mod(R)$ which is actually the infinity category of derived category $D(R)$ and I think in this case things are complicated because the embedding of discrete object into $D(R)$ may not admit a right adjoint $\pi_{0}$ as in the case when we embed discrete things into connective part $D_{\geq 0}$.

O, I see this is due to t is regular.
